# Как изменить размер изоброжения на Python, но так что бы не изменилось соотношение сторон

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как изменить размер изоброжения на Python, но так что бы не изменилось соотношение сторон? Я не могу найти формулу, что бы написал `height = 200` а оно автоматом находило правльный `width`

Comment: По пропорции (было что-то такое в школе). Считаете коэффициент, насколько ширина изменилась: `k = new_height / old_height`. Потом умножаете на этот коэффициент старую ширину, получаете новую ширину.

Comment: если высота была 100, а стала 200, то какой станет ширина, если она была 200?

Answer (score 3):

Вычисляете пропорцию сторон ["aspect ratio"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0) и дальше считаете через неё, достаточно школьного курса арифметики:

```py
aspect_ratio = width / height

new_height = 200
new_width = new_height * aspect_ratio
```